# Only prime number for $p^2+2$ to be prime as well

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that the only prime number $p$ for $p^2+2$ to be prime as well is $p=3$

Comment: $p^2\equiv1\pmod 3$

Answer (score 4):

If $p\neq 3$ then it has form $3k\pm 1$ so $p^2+2=(3k\pm 1)^2+2=9k^2\pm6k+3=3(3k^2\pm 2k+1)$ so wont be prime

Comment: Why hasn't it got a form $3k \pm 2$ as well?

Comment: @BernardM.: Notice that $3k+2 = 3(k+1) - 1$ and $3k-2 = 3(k-1) + 1$, so the formula $3k \pm 1$ covers all the cases different from $3k$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand that

Answer (score -1):

**hint:** If $q = p^2 + 2$ is a prime number, then $p = 3k+1$ or $p = 3k+2$

Comment: I believe that you meant to use $\ne$ instead of $=$.